# Indentation lost after table/figure

Tags: tables, indentation

Does someone know why the indentation specified in the beginning of the document is lost after the table/figure? How could I fix this? My simplified piece of code is:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\setlength{\parindent}{4em}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A}
\section{B}
blabla % not indented because first paragraph

blablabla % indented

blalablablabla % indented
\subsection{C}
blblabla % not indented because first paragraph

blalalblabla % nicely indented
\captionof{table}{caption here}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
    \hline
    \textbf{I} & \textbf{S} & \textbf{M} & \textbf{S}\\
    \hline
    A & 0.75 & G & 30\\
    B & 1.2 & H & 750\\
    C & 15 & I & 2250\\
    D & 7.1 & J & 0.4 \\
    E & 1300 & K & 0.7\\
    & & F & 0-0.2\\
     \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

blablablaaablabla % no indentation anymore

blalblablabla % and here neither
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \caption{caption here}
  \begin{tabular}{cccc}` will look the same (and is the typical approach).

Comment: By the way, if you want to keep this design, you should have a look on the package `booktabs` which will result in much nicer vertical spacing. In short `\usepackage{booktabs}` and then replace the `\hline`s by `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `bottomrule`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is the command `\captionof` that causes the indentation fail. Try to comment it and the indentation is correct. In the documentation of `caption` it is said that "you should use both `\captionof` and `\captionof*` only inside boxes or environments". There is also given a warning during the compilation. That means you need to put the table inside e.g. a `minipage`.

In this case I do not really see the point of not using the floating `table` instead of having it fix in the text.

```
\begin{table}[htb]
  \centering
  \caption{caption here}
  \label{tab:table}
  \begin{tabular}{cccc}
    \hline
    \textbf{I} & \textbf{S} & \textbf{M} & \textbf{S}\\
    \hline
    A & 0.75 & G & 30\\
    B & 1.2 & H & 750\\
    C & 15 & I & 2250\\
    D & 7.1 & J & 0.4 \\
    E & 1300 & K & 0.7\\
    & & F & 0-0.2\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 4):

I guess you're doing

```
\captionof{table}{caption here}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
```

in order to get some vertical space between the caption and the table, but this is wrong: `\captionof` should be in the same environment as the table.

In order to get the vertical spacing, issue

```
\captionsetup{position=above}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{caption}

\setlength{\parindent}{4em}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A}

\section{B}

blabla % not indented because first paragraph

blablabla % indented

blalablablabla % indented

\subsection{C}

blblabla % not indented because first paragraph

blalalblabla % nicely indented
\begin{center}
\captionsetup{position=above}
\captionof{table}{caption here}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
    \hline
    \textbf{I} & \textbf{S} & \textbf{M} & \textbf{S}\\
    \hline
    A & 0.75 & G & 30\\
    B & 1.2 & H & 750\\
    C & 15 & I & 2250\\
    D & 7.1 & J & 0.4 \\
    E & 1300 & K & 0.7\\
    & & F & 0-0.2\\
     \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

blablablaaablabla % indented

blalblablabla % indented

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, you should use the `table` environment with the regular `\caption`, rather than `center` and `\captionof`: you're going to have several page breaking related problems, if you want “here” tables and figures.